# How do we safely pause an EXM email campaign?

Tags: exm

**Background**:
I've written a scheduled task to resume paused email campaigns.

**Requirement**:
In order to test this I need to safely pause a campaign.

**Problem**:
I don't know how to pause a campaign safely.

**Question**:
How do we safely pause an EXM email campaign?

Answer (score 0):

In EXM navigate to the campaign that you wish to pause. Click on the Delivery section, select either to:

Send or activate the message now.

Schedule the message delivery or activation for a later date and enter the relevant date and time.

Schedule a recurring delivery to send the same message multiple times in the specified interval and enter the relevant details in the fields that appear

Note
If you schedule to activate an automated message later, you can specify the start date only or you can specify a start and end date for when the automated message must be active.